# Can the ActionItem text be displayed in a different font? (NativeScript)

Tags: nativescript

Can the ActionBar >> ActionItem text be displayed in a different font?

Specifically, I'd like to use a FontAwesome font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not use a different font unless you use a [custom view](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/action-bar#using-custom-view-in-action-items). You may place a Label / Button within your `ActionItem` and set custom font on it. But doing so may remove the ripple effect from the `ActionItem`.

I would suggest using [nativescript-vector-icons](https://github.com/manojdcoder/nativescript-vector-icons) which may help you convert the font awesome or any icon font into a actual image at runtime which can be used as `icon` on the `ActionItem`.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution - I'll look into that soon.